# Geocode Model not updating on button click

Tags: qml, qt5

Im having an issue getting my GeocodeModel to translate addresses into coordinates and then send it on to the RouteModel. Heres what I think is the relevant code:

```js
Address {
    id: fromAddress
    street: "2193 Lake Louisa Rd"
    city: "Hiawassee"
    country: "United States"
    state: "Georgia"
    postalCode: "30546"
}

Address {
    id: toAddress
    street: "205 N Berrong St"
    city: "Hiawassee"
    country: "United States"
    state: "Georgia"
    postalCode: "30546"
}
...
Button {
    id: testButton2
    text: "route test"
    onClicked: {
        geocodeModel.startCoordinate = QtPositioning.coordinate()
        geocodeModel.endCoordinate = QtPositioning.coordinate()
        geocodeModel.query = fromAddress
        geocodeModel.update();
    }
    anchors.left: testButton1.right
}

GeocodeModel {
    id: geocodeModel
    plugin: mapPlugin

    property int success: 0
    property variant startCoordinate
    property variant endCoordinate

    onCountChanged: {
        if (success == 1 && count == 1) {
            query = toAddress
            update();
        }
    }

    onStatusChanged: {
        if ((status == GeocodeModel.Ready) && (count == 1)) {
            success++
            if (success == 1) {
                startCoordinate.latitude = get(0).coordinate.latitude
                startCoordinate.longitude = get(0).coordinate.longitude
                console.log("We applied the start coords")
            }
            if (success == 2) {
                endCoordinate.latitude = get(0).coordinate.latitude
                endCoordinate.longitude = get(0).coordinate.longitude
                console.log("We applied the end coords")
                success = 0
            if (startCoordinate.isValid && endCoordinate.isValid)
                setRoute(startCoordinate,endCoordinate)

            }
        }

        else if ((status == GeocodeModel.Ready) || (status == GeocodeModel.Error))
            if (status == GeocodeModel.Ready && (count == 0)) {
                console.log("Unsuccessful geocode");
            }
            else if (status == GeocodeModel.Error) {
                console.log("Geocode Error");
            }
            else if (status == GeocodeModel.Ready && (count > 1)) {
                console.log("Ambiguous geocode");
            }

            navMap.geocodeFinished()
    }
    onLocationsChanged: {
        if (count > 0) {
            navMap.center.latitude = get(0).coordinate.latitude
            navMap.center.longitude = get(0).coordinate.longitude
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this all I get back is "Unsuccessful geocode" acting like it never loaded in my addresses into the Model. I dont even hit my success console.logs. Im at a loss

Comment: If count is 0 there is something wrong with your mapPlugin. Which plugin name do use?

Comment: And if I use "osm" as plugin, your adresses are unknown. To you should my be start with a adress where your plugin knows the adress for sure.

Comment: ok Ill try that out, it is osm as the plugin. I should also probably have a geocode model available just for testing addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end Jurgen was right, it ended up being an issue with osm parsing the address